# PivotTable to forecast by date

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, pivot-table

I trying to get this forecast by date into a PivotTable so I can drill down the info for a CSV import. The pivot wizard recognises my data all wrong.

How can I get SKU codes as **ROWS**, all the dates dynamic to additions as **COLUMNS** and the forecast values as **VALUES**?

**Excel Data**
[image: Excel Data]

**Failure**
[image: Latest Attempt Result]

I want the Pivot to mirror what I have, so I can drill the data down to the format

```
SKU, Date, Qty
SKU, Date, Qty
SKU, Date, Qty
SKU, Date, Qty
```

If there is an alternative but easier route that would be great.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't right now. To do as you wish, all dates should be in the same column in your source range. That way, Pivot Table would list all values of the field as you wish. Right now, because each date is a single field, then Excel list all values in each date. I'm afraid you'll need to transpose. Anyways, if you already have the design you want, why you want to use the Pivot Table? Because it looks like you already got what you want with the design you want (sku codes at left, each date in top row).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for taking the time to assist me, I managed to find a solution that I thought I'd share. This doesn't go down the PivotTable route but instead gives me the final result that I needed.

```
  Sub NormaliseTable()
Application.Calculation = xlManual
' start with the cursor in the table
  Dim rTab As Range, C As Range, rNext As Range
  Set rTab = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
  If rTab.Rows.Count = 1 Or rTab.Columns.Count = 1 Then
    MsgBox "Not a well-formed table!"
    Exit Sub
  End If
  Workbooks.Add  ' the sheet for the results
  Set rNext = Range("A1")
  For Each C In rTab.Offset(2, 1).Resize(rTab.Rows.Count - 1, _
         rTab.Columns.Count - 1).Cells
If Not (IsEmpty(C.Value) Or C.Value = "0") Then
      rNext.Value = rTab.Cells(C.Row - rTab.Row + 1, 1)
      rNext.Offset(0, 1).Value = rTab.Cells(1, C.Column - rTab.Column + 1)
      rNext.Offset(0, 2).Value = C.Value
      Set rNext = rNext.Offset(1, 0)
    End If
  Next
  ChDir "\\Client\T$"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="\\Client\T$\M3-FC-IMPORT.csv", FileFormat _
        :=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
End Sub
```

Without the Application Calculation going to manual it would take hours, so I turn it off and on with the macro and its almost instantaneous!

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you got is how you are storing your original data. Right now you are doing something like this:

[image]

And to make the Pivot Table work properly, you need tabular design like this:

[image]

Notice that same SKU code can appear more than once, but at different dates (row 12 and 19, row 13 and 20, and so on).

With this tabular design, then you can do a Pivot Table like you want:

[image]

So you need to transpose the data. I've used some formulas that may help you out a little bit. If you got a lot of data,then I strongly suggest you to use them and then paste values, or the file will be heavily overcharged, slow and so on. This is a way to do it.

[image]

1. First, count how many SKU codes you got (in my image, there are just 7)
2. Second, count how many dates you got (in my image, there are just 2)
3. Below original data, copy the complete group of SKU codes (7) as many times as dates (twice in my case) in the same column.
4. In next column (DATE field), you can use this formula: `=INDEX($B$1:$C$1;1;COUNTIFS($A$12:A12;A12))`
5. In next column (VALUE field) you can use: `=INDEX($B$2:$C$8;MATCH(A12;$A$2:$A$8;0);MATCH(B12;$B$1:$C$1;0))`
6. Just drag down and you should get a new range with data transposed properly. And that new range is a perfect source for a Pivot Table and do what you want. **Paste values!**
7. If you add new extra rows to this new range, you can just change the source of your Pivot Table, and then that new data will be instantly added to your Pivot Table with the design you want.
8. After checking everything is right, delete old data, of course!

I've uploaded a sample to my Gdrive in case it may help for you. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ElEPkk5V3QkME7yLPQuGnU7-wd6fQEd_

Hope you can adapt this to your needs.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help, much appreciated. This sheet has 700 SKU's and 30 weekly dates. It will be used daily with new dates and potentially additional SKU's every so often.

This would work for what I require, i believe i've found a solution with VBA that is a little faster. I'll post it as an answer, feel free to check it out. Its not putting it into a Pivot Table, but it gives me the end result that i required.